# Passing an attribute to a constant object

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm creating a chart using chart.js and I'd like to organize the different options in "small chunks of code". So, I have extracted them into constants.

```
this.chart = new Chart(..., {
  type: "line",
  data: ...,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    layout: LAYOUT_OPTIONS,
    ...
  },
  ...
}

const LAYOUT_OPTIONS = {
  padding: { right: 0 }
}
```

This works fine for almost all the options since they are static values as the `padding` above. However, a few of them are dynamic (they come from the HTML as data attributes) as, for instance, the unit of measure to display on the axis.

Is there a way to pass an attribute to a constant, or should I use a function for that?
For consistency, I'd rather keep everything in constants.

Is there an even better way to organize the options?

Comment: The content of `const someObject` can be changed at will. There is nothing in JS that will stop you from doing `LAYOUT_OPTIONS.margin = '{ left: 0 }'`

Comment: *"...a few of them are dynamic (they come from the HTML as data attributes) as, for instance, the unit of measure to display on the axis..."* Would you show us that please, so we don't have to guess at what it looks like?